# Error when publish to Google play and add to library to gradle

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish my app to Google PLay
Error : "We found that the application uses the old version of the Google Play Developer API. From December 1, 2019, support for versions 1 and 2 of this API will cease. Update it to version 3 before this date. Read more ..."
I found, how to fix it, I need to gradle this library

```
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v3-rev95-1.25.0'
```

But when I build APK, studio show me error

```
<issue
    id="DuplicatePlatformClasses"
    severity="Fatal"
    message="`httpclient` defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don&apos;t have the same problem (for example, for `httpclient` use `HttpUrlConnection` or `okhttp` instead), or repackaging the library using something like `jarjar`."
    category="Correctness"
    priority="8"
    summary="Duplicate Platform Classes"
    explanation="There are a number of libraries that duplicate not just functionality of the Android platform but using the exact same class names as the ones provided in Android -- for example the apache http classes. This can lead to unexpected crashes.&#xA;&#xA;To solve this, you need to either find a newer version of the library which no longer has this problem, or to repackage the library (and all of its dependencies) using something like the `jarjar` tool, or finally, rewriting the code to use different APIs (for example, for http code, consider using `HttpUrlConnection` or a library like `okhttp`).">
    <location
        file="D:\Applications\Radio\app\build.gradle"/>
</issue>
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Follow this link https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/androidpublisher/v3

Comment: @NancyY this link does not help. I added those lines in my code and code just not returning any error but play store is still showing me the same warning. do you have any hint?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to project gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Below code to your app gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v3-rev95-1.25.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this...

```
android {
...

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
 }
}
```